# taskbar shortcuts in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, taskbar

I would like to provide shortcuts to content in my SL5 app from the right click menu on the Win7 taskbar, has anyone done that? I was pleasantly surprised when I saw that right clicking on my pinned Media Player icon gave me a recent history of the music I listened to, would like to bring same concept into my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This video](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/Video/gg607258) should get you on your way. You are looking for a "Jump List".